# #1932 - Table 'soporte.usuarios_servicios' doesn't exist in engine

Tags: mysql

Hace un par de días instale la nueva versión de xampp y lo que hice para no perder mis bds fue copiar las carpetas en una para luego volverlas a poner donde deben ir, tal cual lo hice, ahora salen todas en phpmyadmin pero al querer una tabla de una bd me salta el error.
Es la primera ves que hago esto. ¿Podrían indicarme como lo soluciono?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ese no es el camino recomendado para hacer backup de una BD. Mantienes los archivos pero no garantizas que la metadata se genere correctamente. No sabemos si apagaste todos los servicios de xamppp antes de copiar los archivos (pudieron quedar inconsistentes)

Comment: Que tal bro, bueno, lo que debi haber echo es una backup de las bds, hace ratito me acabo de dar cuenta, gracias igual.